# numpy array IndexError: 'index out of bound' when a mask is inverted or negated

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 arrays one is mask and the other is the labels:

Both arrays have the same shape:

```
(Pdb) L.shape
(178, 201, 101)
(Pdb) MASK.shape
(178, 201, 101)
```

when it reaches to this line:

```
L[~MASK] = 0 
IndexError: 'index 255 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 178'
```

it shows an error that I could not find any reason for that. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
L[np.logical_not(MASK)]
```

The ~ (tilde) operator you are using is a bitwise complement operator, not a logical negation operator.